# Service Start and stop in Universal Windows App

Tags: c#, service, nuget-package, windows-10-universal

I found the following Links in MSDN to help me start and stop the window services.
There is code snippet which tells it is possible to start and stop the service.

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Telnet");
if  ((sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) 
        ||  (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
{
     sc.Start();
}  
else
{
  sc.Stop();
}  
sc.Refresh();
```

for this i need the System.ServiceProcess.dll the dll.

**Namespace**:   System.ServiceProcess
**Assembly**:  System.ServiceProcess (in System.ServiceProcess.dll)

I am trying to add this from NUget and got the error.

**Type Script command :** 
Install-Package System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController -Pre

**Error Message :**

Install-Package : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController 4.1.0-beta-23516 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible 
with win10-arm.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Are you going to submit the app to the store or will it be side loaded for business use?

Comment: It is going toe submit the app to the store.

Comment: In that case, the answer by @Sunteen applies - `Services` are not available in UWP, they're considered legacy. You should research `BackgroundTasks`

Comment: @AjayaNayak any updates? If you have get the result could you please consider to mark the answer?

Answer (score 2):

This namespace `System.ServiceProcess` cannot be supported in uwp. We cannot find this .Net api in [.NET for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx).

Also you can add this reference manually by download the package from [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/). But you will still receive error when you run the code.